How to deal with a collegue that is not programming, but studying carefully the code of others?
I have a collegue in my team that produces minimal amount of code and only if it is related to the core domain of the application we are developing. I have observed him that he is using all of his time to study every single line of the code of his teammates and to study also the domain of the product. Than he puts himself answering for every single domain question even if he has not developed the source code he is answering about. On a personal level it is extremly irritating and it also limits the ability for me and for my teammates to express themselves on domain topics. The developer is extremly shy when taking technical tasks. I have observed that he is exacctly the oposite of shy when helping others with their sometimes technical problems. He acctualy produces quality code in the few occasions he is producing code. I suspect that he intentionaly don't takes or finishes personaly purly technical tasks.
This situation is quite irritating me. How can I address this and ensure that he starts doing technical work while I take more domain tasks? How to make sure that he does not interrupt when someone else comes to me for advice on a domain tasks. It apears that when someone comes to me even though he is sitting on the other end of the room he stands up comes closer and grabs the attention then delivers the help that originaly I have been asked to provide.
Here is the problem:

He is intentionaly not writing code, especialy technical code. This gives him more time to focus on domain and what the others are doing. This also means that the rest of the developers including the tech lead that was me before I stepped down need to compensate.
When a collegue has question and comes to me or another collegue, he stands up from his desk moves to my desk and starts on his own initiative to answer questions that were first directed towards me or someone else. This way next time the colleges don't ask me, but go to him an this is isolating me and the rest as he betones a single point of answers.


If he repeatedly interrupts try saying something like "Thanks Bob, but I've got this" and carry on explaining

So what exactly is the problem? You have a colleague who has learned the code, is able to talk at a technical level about the code and is able to write quality code.  It sounds like this individual is by default a technical lead. Everything you describe, if it's a problem for the company, is a problem that you cannot solve. To be put it simply it's not your job to solve the problems you describe, not that I agree, anything you describe is an actual problem. This colleague sounds very knowledgeable.

I will Edit my question.

What you describe might or might not be a problem your manager feels exists. It doesn’t seem like it’s a problem you can solve as you are not their manager.

How do you know that this is not exactly what is manager told them to do? Having a dedicated domain export isn't a bad thing.

@Hilmar because up to regently the project was extremly understaffed. I preget much took it from the dirt and ressurected it. We just delivered in production, the job is done and they started making me problems.

Check with your manager to determine if these are actual problems, or just you having trouble letting go of your code. "Mothering" impulses toward our work are common among creative folks, but are inappropriate in the software world. It isn't your code. It's the company's code. What they do with it, whether you agree or not, is up to them.

@Pesho - What does "preget" mean? Who started making problems and why is it your responsible to solve those problems? You are no longer the technical lead. Why isn't the technical lead solving these problems?

If this person isn't your direct report there isn't much you can do.
The best you can do is be supportive when they show behavior that you want to encourage. Try to ignore behavior that you don't like.
If this person is a direct report, please update your question. I'll update my answer.

Focus on actual concrete problems

He is intentionaly not writing code, especialy technical code. This give him more time to focus on domain and what the others Are doing

This does not directly cause you a problem. You may disagree with it but it is not causing you a problem.

This also mean that the rest Of the developers including the tech lead that was me before I stepped down need to compensate.

This is your problem, so you raise this to your manager. Make sure you don't just talk about you, but talk about the team and how they need to pick up this slack.
But be aware, you are describing how a Tech Lead is meant to work in a lot of places. To summarise your points from elsewhere:

"more time to focus on domain and what the others Are doing"
"according to my team lead. Tech lead goes to meetings and helps others develop."

This sounds like your Tech Lead is not meant to write lots of code, but help others do it. They are meant to act as a multiplier for the other developers, going to meetings, getting the information, making sure everyone is working on the right things, so the others can just get their heads down and code.

when a collegue has question and comes to me or another collegue. He stands up from his desk moves to my desk and starts on his own initiative to answer questions that were first directed towards me or someone Else. This way next time the colleges dont Ask me, but go to him an this is isolating me and the rest as he betones a single point Of answeres

This could be a problem, if it's just a power-move on his behalf. But possibly he's trying to prevent engineers losing focus from their coding tasks. In my role as a manager I try to do exactly this. Talk to him, explain you're happy to answer them and when he next does it say something like "Thanks Steve but I can handle this. I know this code". If he keeps doing it raise it your manager. But be aware these questions are possibly taking you away from what should be your main focus.
It distinctly sounds like the cause of your problems is you have a different idea of what a Tech Lead should be than your company. Ultimately you may have to make peace with that, or move on.

Fortunately, your job is not to answer questions, your job is to get tickets done. Does he get tickets? Is he ready with them? In time?
...if yes, you have a helpful teammate knowing more about the domain as you all. It is not your problem to fix the case, probably there is not too much to fix.
If not... well, also that is not your job.
If he asks you, answer as you can. If you want to figure out something, maybe he already knows that. :-)
I see very dangerous line, in your post, that it looks as if you would fear for your source code from your own teammates. It is bad, very bad. You are the same company, the same team. If others check, and understand your work, that is not a threat et all. That means, they can directly experience your programming greatness.
Normally, bosses and leads only see your jira progress, but not your git progress.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Is this one of the same people you were complaining about in your last question? If he really is not producing any business value, his manager will slap him down at review time. Notice that the value may in fact be in review, or other non-coding tasks.
If you really want to stick your nose into this, schedule a conversation with your manager, tell him that you are confused by what this person is contributing to the group, and listen while they explain rather than assuming that you know better.
But managing your peers is not part of your job. Leave it alone. Focus on increasing your value to the company. This should not be considered a zero-sum game; you can win without somebody else losing, and you gain points faster if you accept that other people gain points too.
Actually, one of the fastest way to gain points is to support others. People who are willing to focus on architecture, review, documentation, support, and testing, if they do it well, are worth their weight in gold even if they never originate a single line of code. That may be what you have here. If so, your complaint is entirely inappropriate; they are doing exactly the job they are supposed to be doing.

"even if they never originate a single line of code" Such people often reduce the number of lines of code in a project... And as bugs per line of code is pretty constant for any project, reducing the lines of code means that that the number of bugs have been reduced as well.

Its sounds like you have a real tech lead at your company. As opposed to a first among code monkeys that is more commonly seen. And that appears to be what you expect a tech lead to be (explains why people got mad at you when you were the tech lead, and why you were replaced as tech lead by this guy).
You can tell that he is a tech lead instead of the first among code monkey's by a couple of his behaviors.

Observed him that he is using all of his time to study every single line of the code of his teammates and to study also the domain of the product

He reads other peoples code, and understand it. The primary job of a tech lead is to ensure code quality/understand the project well enough that your team can send 1 person to the stupid meetings who has all the answers, instead of wasting everyone on your teams time by sending everyone to every single meeting.

He spends more time studying the domain then writing code

So he is a software engineer who is solving difficult problems that require a lot of thought/effort and not a code monkey printing out boiler plate. I spend more time solving problems then I spend time spewing out code. I'd rather spend 2 hours thinking and 1 hour coding than 16 hours spewing out lines of code and hoping I solved it thru effort.

He answers questions about the product as a whole instead of only answering questions about things he worked on.

From your complaint I assume that his answers are all correct (otherwise I would assume that you would have mentioned how often he is wrong). That he understands how everything works well enough to answer questions on things he hasn't worked on says he understands the project as a whole, and is a good tech lead. He is also increasing your team's bus factor (allowing people to have holidays) by understanding other developers work well enough to answer questions about their work. While simultaneously reducing the number of interruptions other engineers experience throughout the day.

He has done this often enough that engineers have now started asking him technical questions instead of asking other engineers.

Yeah, that's the point of a tech lead. They get their work interrupted constantly by stupid questions so that the people who are doing the work can get things done without interruptions.

he has become the single point of answers...

This sounds a bit like jealousy to me.
TLDR:
A tech leads job isn't to write code. It is to understand the domain/project and ensure that the team produces a quality product.

"I'd rather spend 2 hours thinking and 1 hour coding than 16 hours" Okay, we all know that this is a lie. I'd rather spend 16 hours coding then 2 hours thinking and an hour coding. Coding is fun and I feel so smart spewing out arcane symbols on the text editor and watching the results unfold before my eyes. Thinking is hard

This is an excellent answer.

@Questor. No it is not jealousy, if I had the same behaviour with another 2 juniors in the team this project would have finished like NEVER EVER. Since he was not producing enogh I had to compensate for him, when I am the position tech lead. This is called moral compass, not jealousy.

@Questor also the people that were unhappy were mostly out of the team. I was using one post agile style with no hierarchy which made some agile couches in the company not happy as they were pushing for their thing, so it is not exactly the team mates that were unhappy.

@Pesho "Now I think it is a matter of time until the others start complaining about it. The key thing here is that this is not the first time I am in a similar situation"... If one person has a complaint. It could be on them. But if this has happened multiple times with many different people, its time for some introspection as you might be the problem.

I could be completely off the mark on some or all of this answer. This answer is just based on my interpretation of what you have said in this question (and a previous similarly downvoted question). If I am wrong I apologize for any offense I have caused. But I feel that the content of this answer is useful to other people that are in a similar boat.
If you have only ever worked under extreme go horse. Than having a tech lead that actually does their job, can be a bit disconcerting., and will make you feel like they aren't doing what they are "supposed" to.
